# Error when converting from Java to Kotlin. Error - org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am converting my Android project from Java to Kotlin. I have done this process with 3 other projects already and successfully.

But this one a little large and has a complicated structure. I've converted some files to Kotlin and project compiles. But there are some files throws compile exception when I convert them to Kotlin.

Compile issue I'm facing appears in Debug and Release mode. Short is as following (Have listed all below)

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. 
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
```

What do you think, how can I solve the problem?

I think this is a bug in Android Studio.

**I have tried. Has not any result:**

- *Invalidate Caches/Restart*
- *Build -> Clean Project*
- *Update kotlin plugin, used the latest version of kotlin, google APIs.*

**My app build.gradle is:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        applicationId "package.id"
        versionCode 10
        versionName "2.5.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }            
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':androidViewUtilslibrary')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
    compile 'com.mobapphome.library:mah-ads:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.mobapphome.library:mah-android-updater:1.1.7'
    compile 'com.mobapphome.library:mah-encryptor-lib:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')

    //For testing
    // App's dependencies, including test
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    compile project(':libCommonNotations')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Top level build.gradle:**

```
common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Error log I'm facing:**

***with option: --info  --stacktrace***

```
Using kotlin incremental compilation e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.hummatli.view.MainActivity, unresolved supertypes: DlgGeneralListener

[KOTLIN] deleting /Volumes/Disk_2/projects/Project/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
[KOTLIN] deleting /Volumes/Disk_2/projects/Project/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
:app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
:app:compileDebugKotlin (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 0.61 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:291)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:265)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:168)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:147)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.431 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=896, address=[46c9a211-21e2-41b0-bb5e-0e1b5552400b port:50150, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1499244624479, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=e2bdc700-5856-41ee-bb69-75c0a63ea675,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk_from_intteluj_for_sierra_problem/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/ss/.gradle/daemon,pid=896,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
```

Comment: Try gradle clean command

Comment: As I mentioned above, I've already done this. @just

Comment: Ok, sorry, try with an older kotlin version?

Comment: Can you add `--info --stacktrace` to your gradle command to see more output

Comment: Try to update android studio

Comment: Exception log added above are with this option . `--info --stacktrace ` @guenhter

Comment: I have latest stable version of Android Studio 2.3.3, Built on june 6, 2017. @A.Shevchuk

Comment: @SattarHummatli You just put the stacktrace in here. There should be some logging before and/or afterwards too which can be helpful

Comment: @guenhter, Sorry.  I added stacktrace with log. Does it help?

Comment: What does the log before `:app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED` says? The error should be listed there.

Comment: @guenhter, Yes you are right. Error was there. I have added it before log.

Comment: I got a similar error because I forgot to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` on a module's `build.gradle` file (in a multimodule project).

Answer (score 4):

The class `DlgGeneralListener` is missing in your classpath.
Ensure that

- The library (jar-file) containing this class is on the classpath
- OR if the class is part of your project, that the classfile is contained